# What are the .map files used for in angular-cli and can ng build not create these files?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

ng build of angular-cli creates 3 files:

```
inline.bundle.js
vendor.bundle.js
main.bundle.js
```

and also a map file for each own. What for?

I am also asking if there is a way to change that behavior, not creating these 3 files but copy to dist directory all the js files, not bundle anything. Is that possible?

Comment: source maps, for debugging

Comment: what do you mean? these files are all the js code around the project, are the map will let me debug the code as I wrote it, or the compile code from (changed from ts to js)?

Comment: TypeScript transpiles your code into something that will work in a browser, as browsers don't run TypeScript. The map files point that code (in the browser) to the actual source files that are written in TS. That makes it easier to figure out at what line in the actual source things are going wrong.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`.map` files are used for debugging your application. It is not related with angular-cli and is feature of typescript compiler, you may set\unset in tsconfig file like below,

```
 "sourceMap": true\false
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I would add, however, that you probably do not want to turn them off!

Comment: But once i ran ,`ng build --aot --prod` angular will automatically remove `.map` files , i haven't set `sourceMap` to `false` yet. how's it possible any comments on this ?

Comment: also can you please elaborate bit more what does it mean exactly by `...debugging your application` ? debugging in what terms ?

Comment: @PardeepJain, well when cli minify your code , it is hard to debug and sourcemap enables you do the same by creating a link between your minified JS and source JS\typescript , read more about it [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Comment: @PardeepJain, For `ng build --aot --prod` , Angular CLI configures so that source map is not generated in production mode, you may see all the default settings which are applied [here explaining --dev vs --prod builds](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#--dev-vs---prod-builds)

Comment: Hi, where it saves the relevant *.map for using in Internet Explorer, for example?

Answer (score 10):

@Madhu's answers disables it for any `ng build` command. If you want to conditionally or temporarily disable it from your builds run:

**Angular 8**

`ng build --watch --source-map=true/false`

**Angular 7**

`ng build --watch --sourcemaps=true/false`

**Angular 6**

`ng build --watch --no-sourcemap`

Comment: For Angular 7+, you want `ng build --sourceMap=true`. [Here](https://angular.io/cli/build) is the latest Angular documentation.

Comment: Apparently, it’s `--sourcemaps=true`, not _sourceMap_.

Comment: For Angular 8 `ng build --source-map=false` (or `true`)

Comment: Thanks @JFK and @ Mormegil. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below command will not generate the source files while generating the build:

> **>ng build --prod -sm false**

and if you want to generate the source files the use below command:

> **>ng build --prod -sm true**

Here is the screenshot:

[image]