# how many files should be there after ng build in dist folder

Tags: angular, ng-build

I have a angular 7 application, where i created multiple modules. Now when i build using ng build, it builds and creates js files inside the dist folder like 
scripts.js 
vendor.js and also for each module in the app it creates like the below

> ### my-profile-my-profile-module.js.map
>
> > ### my-profile-my-profile-module.js
> >
> > ### service-reports-module.js.map
>
> ### service-reports-module.js
>
> ### ...

My question is this normal or there has to be only two files i.e scripts.js and vendor.js inside dist folder

I have tried ng build --prod  , it still creates the same files except the size reduction of the files

Comment: check here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118760/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-angular-cli-and-can-ng-build-not-create-thes

Comment: This is perfectly normal and this is the expected output. You get a js file for each module when you have lazy-loading.

Comment: thanks for the reply. my question is not about .map files, will ng build create js files for modules too?

Comment: @Arul ok, thanks, but how to avoid generating multiple files? any ways to edit the webpack file etc ?

Comment: When you have configured Lazy-loading, you will get separate files for each module. When you disable lazy-loading and use eager loading, you will get single file for all modules. Why do you want to have single file?