# Not all compiled files go to the output main.js

Tags: angular, building, transpiler

I have noticed that some of my `.ts` files are compiled into the files with the name that is combination of the path where they are located and their names, instead of going to the `main.js` (e.g. the file located in the `src/app/admin/accounts/max-flow-schedules/auto-generator.module.js` is compiled into file `src_app_admin_accounts_max-flow-schedules_auto-generator_module_ts.js`)
Does that indicate some problems with the compilation?

Comment: This is not a problem, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603284/how-many-files-should-be-there-after-ng-build-in-dist-folder.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the answer.