# How to Show in the Console the Correct Location of a log in an Angular Component instead of main.js?

Tags: angular, debugging, logging, program-entry-point, console.log

In the console, I get an undesired location of a log that I placed in an angular component of a project that I am building.
Instead of getting the location of the log in my project e.g.
Hello world myComponent.js:33
I get:
Hello world main.js:333
This is an image of the problem and the desired result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxcPr.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/einkR.png

Comment: Are you by any chance building your code into a single file? (called main.js) If so - the browser is not aware of this fact.  Consider checking [source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118760/what-are-the-map-files-used-for-in-angular-cli-and-can-ng-build-not-create-thes) in order to help your browser figure out what the original file is. If you are using a logging tool (like sentry) you presumably need to integrate your source maps with it too.

Comment: Hello Benjamin. Thank you for your answer. I have written the code of my project into different files and folders, I checked the file tree of the project in vscode and none of them is called main.js. This is a link to an image of the problem, I hope that it usefull: https://imgur.com/a/CB2SEQK

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit this post to add this image to be more specific but there there is no edit button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxcPr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the project? Seems like Angular is building the app before serving...
When you build your project Angular transforms all your components code into a single main.js file.

Comment: Hello João. Thank you for your reply. In the terminal, I ran ng serve then the program compiles then in the browser I open http://localhost:4200/. This problem only happens after the computer wakes up from sleep mode. I think I once ran ng build in the terminal but I am not sure. This is an image of the problem: https://imgur.com/a/CB2SEQK